# Is the colon symbol interchangeable with the set membership symbol in the Z specifications language?

Tags: specifications, formal-languages

In the Z specifications language, is the colon symbol ':' a mere variation of the set membership symbol '∈'? Can they always be used interchangeably? In particular, are the following expressions legal in Z?

[image: A lambda expression and a set description expression using the set membership symbol]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*IMHO*, **No**.

Although every set **can be used** as a type [[source: page 11](https://formal.iti.kit.edu/~beckert/teaching/Spezifikation-SS04/11Z.pdf)], the syntax for **declaring a variable** `x` of type `T` is well-defined and it unambiguously uses only the colon symbol `:` [[source: page 15](https://formal.iti.kit.edu/~beckert/teaching/Spezifikation-SS04/11Z.pdf)].

The subtle distinction between the notion of *Type* and the notion of *membership-of* is that a variable `x` can be only of one given *Type*, but it may belong to (possibly infinitely) many *Sets*.

Since this type of writing qualifies as an **abuse of notation**, you may be required to include a disclaimer in your research paper/document that clarifies the notation you are using, and what is the advantage in doing so *(I see none)*. On this regard, I would invite you to look at the research literature and at your peers and try to stick to the convention used by the surrounding environment.

---

This

```
{ x ∈ Z | x < 100 }
```

does not respect the syntax for **set comprehensions**:

> ```
> { x : T | pred(x) ● expr(x) }
> ```
>
> The set of all elements that result from evaluating
>   `expr(x)` for all `x` of type `T` for which `pred(x)`
>   holds.
>
> When `expr(x)` is equal to `x`, i.e. when we return 
>   the element itself, we can omit `expr(x)` and write
>
> ```
> { x : T | pred(x) }
> ```
>
> [[source: pages 7,8](https://formal.iti.kit.edu/~beckert/teaching/Spezifikation-SS04/11Z.pdf)]

---

This

```
λx ∈ Z • x + 1
```

does not respect the syntax for **lambda functions** [[source: page 24](https://formal.iti.kit.edu/~beckert/teaching/Spezifikation-SS04/11Z.pdf)]:

> ```
>  λa : S | p • e
> ```